# ComparisonFailure in EasMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I have below method which i want to test using EasyMock.

```
public String createNode(Session session, String name) throws RepositoryException {
    Node root = session.getRootNode();
    Node testNode = root.getNode( "content" );
    if( !testNode.hasNode(name) ) {
        testNode.addNode( name, "nt:unstructured" );
    }
    return testNode.getPath()+"/"+name;
}
```

And test method is :

```
@Test
public void createNodeTest() throws RepositoryException {   
    final Session SESSION_MOCK = EasyMock.createNiceMock((Session.class));
    final Node ROOT_NODE_MOCK = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Node.class);
    final Node CONTENT_NODE_MOCK = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Node.class);
    final Node CHILD_NODE_MOCK = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Node.class);

    EasyMock.expect(SESSION_MOCK.getRootNode()).andReturn(ROOT_NODE_MOCK);       
    EasyMock.expect(ROOT_NODE_MOCK.getNode("content")).andReturn(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK);        
    EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.hasNode("viv")).andReturn(false);        
    EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.addNode("viv","nt:unstructured")).andReturn(CHILD_NODE_MOCK);        
    EasyMock.expect(CHILD_NODE_MOCK.getPath()).andReturn("/content/viv");
    EasyMock.replay(SESSION_MOCK,ROOT_NODE_MOCK,CONTENT_NODE_MOCK);       

    TestableClass tc = new TestableClass();
    assertEquals("/content/viv", tc.createNode(SESSION_MOCK,"viv"));          

    EasyMock.verify(SESSION_MOCK,CONTENT_NODE_MOCK,ROOT_NODE_MOCK);     
}
```

Getting failure :

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[/content]/viv> but was:<[null]/viv>

Anyone can tell where i am wrong, i want to get the test pass.
Thanks

Comment: If you switch from `createNiceMock` to `createMock` EasyMock will throw an exception when it sees a call it is unprepared for. You may need to add some extra calls to `expect(...).andStubReturn(...)`, but in any case it'll help with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is coming around these lines in your method:

```
if( !testNode.hasNode(name) ) {
    testNode.addNode( name, "nt:unstructured" );
}
return testNode.getPath()+"/"+name;
```

The expectations you have set up for it are as follows:

```
EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.hasNode("viv")).andReturn(false);        
EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.addNode("viv","nt:unstructured")).andReturn(CHILD_NODE_MOCK);        
EasyMock.expect(CHILD_NODE_MOCK.getPath()).andReturn("/content/viv");
```

The problem is that your code doesn't use the response from the `addNode()` method, but your test expectations are set up such that the code *would* use the response from the `addNode()` method.

The way I see it you have 2 options:

1. If the code is correct, then you need to adjust your expectations to something like this:

   ```
   EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.hasNode("viv")).andReturn(false);        
   EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.addNode("viv","nt:unstructured")).andReturn(CHILD_NODE_MOCK);        
   EasyMock.expect(CONTENT_NODE_MOCK.getPath()).andReturn("/content/viv");
   ```
2. If the test is correct (that'd be nice, TDD and all that) then you need to alter your code to look like this:

   ```
   Node childNode = testNode; //Or some other valid creation
   if( !testNode.hasNode(name) ) {
       childNode = testNode.addNode( name, "nt:unstructured" );
   }
   return childNode.getPath()+"/"+name;
   ```